# Gradle Maven Publish Plugin with Multiple JDK

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a Java library project that I wanted to publish using Maven Publish Plugin. The challenge that I have is I wanted to publish it to the same local nexus repository but compiled using multiple JDK versions. Like I wanted to compile same source using JDK 1.8 and JDK 11. The reason I am doing that is because, I have multiple consumers to my project and wanted to make sure I am able to provide the correct artifact.

I got this Idea from seeing the Microsoft's MSSQL Server drivers. They have same version of the drivers published specifically for individual JDKs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you always want to compile for Java 8 (both for JDK 1. and JDK 11)?

Comment: Yes. I would want it to be compiled and published in their own JDK

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. So do you want to compile for Java 8 when using JDK 11, or do you want to compile for Java 11 when using JDK 11?

Comment: Yes. While publishing artifact for jre8 I want to compile in JDK8. While publishing JRE11 artifact, I wanted to compile using JDK11. In this way the compiled artifact matches the correct JRE.

Comment: What is a JRE 11 artifact? An artifact that should run on JRE 11? An artifact that is compiled for Java 11? Or and artifact that is compiled with JDK 11?

Comment: Are my questions not clear?

Comment: Actually I have code written using JDK 1.8 and I am currently publishing them to our nexus as JDK 1.8 artifacts. Recently there are some applications that use this artifact are migrated to Java 11. So I wanted to compile the code written for Java 1.8 for Java 11 clients and still support other clients who have not fully migrated to Java 11.

Comment: If your artifacts are built for Java 8 with JDK 1.8, you can use them on JDK 11 as well. Why create two different versions?

Comment: Please note that there are three different things: The JDK you compile with, the Java version you compile for and the JDK you run on. These need not be the same.

Comment: Good to know. I will let you know if this works.

Comment: So what was the solution you eventually came up with for this, @reflexdemon?

Answer (score 0):

The use case you described is precisely the use case for which [*Multi-Release JAR Files*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/238) were invented.

[*The* ***mrJar*** *Gradle plugin*](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.lingocoder.mrjar) is a plugin that was invented precisely for that very MRJAR use case.

In fact, the ***mrJar*** plugin uses itself to create the very JAR that it is published to the plugin portal in. It *dog foods* itself in its build process to create a [*Modular Multi-Release JAR*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/238#Modular-multi-release-JAR-files) artifact that gets distributed from the plugin repository.

For example: Only versions of Gradle 6.0 or higher support Java 13. The JAR file of the ***mrJar*** plugin that is published on Gradle's plugin portal has the smarts to only provide Java 13 support only when it is applied in a project running in Java 13. When the plugin is running in Java 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 the Java 13 features are non-existent.

I'm pretty sure using the ***mrJar*** plugin is the solution to the use case your question describes. [*These Usage instructions*](http://lingocoder.com/mrjar/mrjar.usage.html) will step you through what you need to do.

Comment: Can you please throw some example that I can look into? There is not enough documentation on the link you provided for me to experiment.

Comment: @reflexdemon I added a link to the usage instructions to the answer. I haven't updated that page recently. But for your use case, the steps are still exactly the same for the current version that they were for that older version.

Comment: The usage instructions state that "Due to a breaking change in Gradle 5.6.1, current versions of mrJar are confirmed to work only with Gradle versions 5.0.0 to 5.5.1".

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @StefanBollmann. That usage page isn't updated as diligently as it should be. Apologies. Please try [*version 0.0.16*](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.lingocoder.mrjar)? Version 0.0.16  was updated and tested with Gradle 6.0-rc-2. If you have any problems with that one, please [*provide the details of it in this issue tracker*](https://github.com/lingocoder/mrJardularity)?. I will investigate it for you A.S.A.P.    A minimal reproducible example— *with steps to reproduce the issue, JDK, OS, etc* —would help me arrive at a resolution for you very quickly. TIA.

Comment: @reflexdemon. How did you do? I updated the plugin after we last spoke. If your experiment resulted in any errors, please try [*version 0.0.16*](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.lingocoder.mrjar)? Version 0.0.16 was updated and tested with Gradle 6.0-rc-2. If you have any problems with that version, please [*provide the details of it in this issue tracker*](https://github.com/lingocoder/mrJardularity)? I will investigate it for you A.S.A.P.    A minimal reproducer — *with steps to reproduce the issue, a Gradle wrapper, which JDK you used, OS, etc* —would mean a quicker resolution. TIA.

Comment: Ever since I asked this question and explored different options, we migrated all the applications to JAVA 11. Now the new standard for clients is JDK 11 within the organization. However, I still have requests within my org to have support for jdk 8. I will give it a go when those projects are worked on in future. However, currently working on other unrelated projects and plan to pick this work in Q1 2021.